# How do I create buttons that reset and pause a timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton

How do I make the two buttons that are displayed reset / pause the timer? The timer works but I want to change the code for the buttons so that they will change the timer instead of outputting to the console. Thank you.

CODE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class createWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new createWindow();
}//end main

createWindow()
{
    super("Frame");
    setSize(400,70);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    show();

        final JLabel time = new JLabel("Timer");
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset timer");
        JButton pause = new JButton("Pause timer");
        reset.setActionCommand("resetClicked");
        pause.setActionCommand("pauseClicked");
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        pause.addActionListener(this);
        add(pause);
        add(time);
        add(reset);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true)
        {
            long  timer = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            final int seconds = (int) (timer / 1000);
            String display = Integer.toString(seconds);
            time.setText(display);
        }//end while loop
    }//end constructor

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    String buttonClicked = e.getActionCommand();
    if(buttonClicked.equals("resetClicked"))
    {
        System.out.println("The reset button was clicked"); //Change to reset timer
    }
    else if(buttonClicked.equals("pauseClicked"))
    {
        System.out.println("The pause button was clicked"); //Change to pause timer
    }
}//end listener
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an infinite `while` loop. This blocks the `EDT`. Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). This will give you control to start and stop the `Timer`.

[Stopwatch Example](http://ccac2.com/KKode/StopWatch/StopWatch.htm)

---

*Side Notes:*

- Don't use `JFrame.show` as that method is *deprecated*. Use `JFrame.setVisible` instead. Also make this call when all components have been added to the frame.
- The functionality for the `JButtons` is sufficiently different to warrant using separate `ActionListener` instances for each button.
- The preferred approach is to use a `JFrame` instance directly rather then extending it.
- Class names in Java begin with uppercase so `createWindow` would become `CreateWindow`.